# SqlCmd Variable for Dacpac Deployment in TFS 2015 vNext Release For Database Projects

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have an error like this - ##[error]Deployment failed: 'An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.' Reason: 'Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:Test1.' ''.  I know Dacpac deployment could not support SqlCmd variables before TFS 2015.

However in TFS 2015 Releases' Database Deployment task, I see the SqlCmd Variables can be configured.

[image]

Does that mean TFS 2015 support that now?  If so, what is the format to type in the variable and values?

Also can anyone find any document about the Database Deployment task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tasks come from an extension.  The format of the variable input can be found in https://github.com/TechnossusLLC/On-Premises-Release-Toolkit/blob/master/deploydatabase.md

Comment: Link is broken.  Since SO discourages link only answers, you should put a copy of the information in your answer.